# Gnome desktop - Top bar font gone mad

Tags: fonts, 17.04, gnome-classic

I just updated Ubuntu to version 17.04.
When logging back after rebooting, GNOME seems to be behaving strangely:

Rogue top bar:

[image]

This strange "font" is used everywhere by the GNOME launcher:

Rogue launcher:

[image]

I've tried to reset the font using `gnome-tweak-tool`, but it doesn't change a thing.

How could this happen ? How can I set or reset the font ?

Comment: Does the issue persist after a reload of Gnome Shell? You can reload it either through (1) logout & login or (2) the Gnome Shell command line (open with Alt+F2 by default) command `r` (press Enter to run the command). Option (2) will retain all running applications and their windows.

Comment: I'll try reloading, but rebooting doesn't change a thing @David

Comment: I upgraded to 17.10, and with it the Gnome Desktop. I'm also having a lot of font problems, but they seem to be limited to 3rd party apps.

Comment: @tim hmm my problems are limited to the system, all fonts in apps behave normally... Anyway I hope upgrading to 17.10 'll fix my problems ..?

Comment: Dang. I just lost everything I had typed to you. Short version is that I'm seeing a couple of issues. Some cases where I get brackets (a little different than yours) in one 3rd party app, but the biggest issue is that several of my fonts (i.e., 3rd party app title bars) have different backgrounds or are otherwise not clear. I downloaded Atom, and when I open a file dialogue, the character background is dark black while the characters are dark gray. I'm still searching for a solution.

Comment: Well, I sang a song, did a little dance, threw some chicken bones against the wall, and deleted .gconf from my user folder. Those steps seemed to address most of my issues.

Comment: @tim I'll consider the chicken bone dance :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue.

My solution was like so:

- open a terminal (alt F2, gnome-terminal)
- sudo apt-get remove fonts-cantarell
- sudo apt-get install fonts-cantarell

And all fonts appear.

Comment: I'll try that as soon as l can.

Answer (score 0):

Try navigating to fonts in the Tweak Tool. To help you, here is a picture of the Tweak Tool's font section:[image]
Once you are able to get to fonts, just try changing the font to anything Cantarell. It doesn't matter if it is Bold or Italic, you are just trying to apply a random font. Hope this fixed your problem.

Comment: somehow it's even worse : doing that seems to spread the infection.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is not OS-Wide, then you can create a new user and copy your files over to said user. Once all your files are on the new user you can delete the old user.

Comment: That's probably the most convenient solution. But I'm sure this isn't the best way.