# Garbled menu items in some application (mostly games) in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome, gui

[image]

In some of the apps, mostly games or kids application I see the menu items are no longer english, but rather these gibberish. Any clue please?
I've checked the locale, its en_US.UTF8, all seems correct there.

Comment: Wrong font in use. See solution for a similar issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/958147/gnome-desktop-top-bar-font-gone-mad

Comment: Thanks but Nope, none of that is relevant to my problem. I don't have font cantarel or whatever.

Comment: But, it is using the wrong font. The aforementioned link shows how to use the Tweak Tool gnome-tweak-tool to change the default font; Cantarell is irrelevant, and I qualified that by noting this was a _similar_ issue.